# Designing a function to output the smallest plurality winner possible

Tags: r, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

I'm trying to design a function/formula where you're given two integer variables representing, say for example, 5 and 100. The first number could represent 5 ice cream flavours on a survey, and the 100 the number of people being sampled being asked their favourite ice cream.

I want to design a function/formula which would produce the combination of numbers where 1 of the 5 ice cream flavour's can win by smallest plurality (so, I'm guessing in most cases, by 1), and have the smallest number possible based on the number of ice cream flavours on the survey.

So with 5 ice cream flavour's and 100 respondents, I would want R to produce a vector of (order not really important):

```
[1] 21 20 20 20 19
```

As 21 is the smallest number possible for a majority ice cream flavour winner out of 100 respondants and 5 flavours. As a function it would need to deal with when numbers of choices don't neatly divide with the numeber of respondants as well.

**Desired output**

```
combinations_function <- function(x, y) {
  ?????
}

combinations_function(5, 100)
[1] 21 20 20 20 19

combinations_function(5, 38)
[1] 9 8 7 7 7

combinations_function(7, 48)
[1] 8 7 7 7 7 6 6
```

Comment: Tried adding it but I really don't know where to begin. Maybe this question is better suited for maths.stackexchange

Comment: Do ties work? 21, 20, 20, 20, 19 would be a smaller. Plus, examples of uneven amounts would be helpful. Maybe 38 and 5 would or any random combo.

Comment: Surely you want the output to be `21 20 20 20 19`?

Comment: Thanks I changed it, not thinking right. I added a different example as well. Ties are okay in the non-winning ice cream flavours. @markus unfortunately no, but hopefully my added example makes it clearer what I'm looking for.

Comment: I've removed the extra tags; this is a simple algebra problem, not an algorithm or combinatorics.  You've already worked out the solution by hand.

Comment: Also, please note that what you're trying to compute is a *plurality*, not a majority.

Comment: Noted, I got the terms mixed up, thanks. I don't understand the need to downvote and request to close this question though? I haven't found a previous question asking something similar and I did my examples by mental solution without any algorithmic process and I'm still working on designing the function.

Comment: It's actually a bit ambiguous @Prune! "Henry Watson Fowler suggests that the American terms "plurality" and "majority" offer single-word alternatives for the corresponding two-word terms in British English, "relative majority" and "absolute majority", and that in British English "majority" is sometimes understood to mean "receiving the most votes" and can therefore be confused with "plurality".. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurality_(voting). I'm from the UK and we commonly use majority to mean "plurality". But I guess changing the question to plurality helps clear up that ambiguity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think I got it:

```r
smallest_margin <- function(choices, respondents)
{
    values = rep(respondents %/% choices, choices)
    remainder = respondents %% choices
    while(remainder != 0)
    {
      values[which.min(values)] <- values[which.min(values)] + 1
      remainder = remainder - 1
    }
    if(length(which(values == max(values))) > 1)
      values[which(values == max(values))[1:2]] <- 
      values[which(values == max(values))[1:2]] + c(-1, 1)
    return(sort(values))
}

smallest_margin(5, 100)
# [1] 19 20 20 20 21
smallest_margin(1, 100)
# [1] 100
smallest_margin(5, 99)
# [1] 19 19 20 20 21
smallest_margin(12, 758)
# [1] 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 65
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a *code-golfian* approach

```
f <- function(x,y) 
  rep(y%/%x, x) + ifelse(rep(y%%x>0, x), 
                         c(1^(1:(y%%x)), 0*((y%%x+1):x)), 0) + c((-1)^(0:1), 0*(3:x))
```

**Example**

```
f(5, 100)
# [1] 21 19 20 20 20
f(5, 38)
# [1] 9 7 8 7 7
f(5, 48)
# [1] 11  9 10  9  9
f(7, 48)
# [1] 8 6 7 7 7 7 6
```

Comment: Nice! You can cleave off a few further characters by taking the strong binding of the `:` operator into account, so this could fit on a single SO line as `f<-function(x,y)1^(1:x)*y%/%x+ifelse(y%%x*1:x>0,c(1^(1:(y%%x)),0*(y%%x+1):x),0)+c(0:1*2-1,0*3:x)`

Comment: @AllanCameron I purposefully did not go all the way for some readability haha But here would be my version ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcttC4JADAfw936KQQgbnnSz8qnMDxKJD3gghIUVnESf/TqVIrbbn92PDUbBwQf17JtHd@1Ri1GUeZkN7Y3Mq8pGd@3qfW3TBla5Jq9T7eXeYn2UuRYNcoGc1iTs5k9BXoPoMxUoU16@A3obhTsBLCU5KzjxGQIGTiCQSzszb@KvJhBBbF@0wPYHzGCR5TQhsRr9awzhdDRXaD4 "R – Try It Online")) `f <- function(x,y,`?`=rep){a=y%/%x;b=y%%x;(a?x)+ifelse(b>0?x,c(1^(1:b),0?x-b),0)+c((-1)^(0:1),0?x-2)}`